# Tweets Labeling techniques

Tags: python, annotations, tweets, labeling

I am working on twitter data analytics personal project, especially Arabic tweets. I am currently on preprocessing phase, 
I already save the streamed tweets in JSON files, I need to label tweets to pos and neg. is there any way to add the label directly to the json file or how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the JSON's and annotate each tweet in an iteration, then you need to overwrite that JSON file or you could save it in another. There's no way to do direct edits in the file.

You'll have to use the [Python JSON module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: Thanks, what if I am dealing with big data? is there any tool which could help? any idea?

Comment: @Eng.shohso by big data you mean you have a continuously growing JSON or a number of JSON's? In any case, I wouldn't recommend using JSON or JSON file storing for big data... when you're talking about big data we are talking about literraly hundreds of GB or even TB of data. I think other form of storages are more appropriate for this. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I was capturing a stream of tweets into JSON files based on a list of keywords for more than 3 months. The resulting big files contain millions of tweets in json format. I am trying to parse all these files and extract specific fields like text, location..etc and save them into one csv file for further processing and text mining.

Comment: @Eng.shohso And why aren't you using a database + elasticsearch for this? Makes your life way easier for text searching.